# TYPO3 6.1 + macina_banner 1.5.3 : Redirect fail after migration to HTTPS

Tags: caching, https, typo3, browser-cache, typo3-extensions

TYPO3 6.1 + Macina banner
macina_banners 1.5.3
Tested on Chrome and Firefox

I use EXT: macina_banners to display banners

Everything was working fine until I switched to HTTPS.
After migrating to HTTPS, redirect stop working

Since I changed to HTTPS, a click on the banner reloads the same page, and redirect does not work.

When I am logged in TYPO3 backend, when I click on the banner it still reloads the same page, but if after that I reload the page with ctrl+MAJ+R, I am redirected to the target page.

If I reload the page with ctrl+MAJ instead of ctrl+MAJ+R, it just reloads the same page with no redirect.

I am a bit confused because It looks like a cache issue, but the problem appears only with HTTPS, and everything works fine with my dev website which is HTTP.

I have checked the ext code, I didn't find anything (but I am not a php expert).
I have deleted the content of typo3temps, it didn't solve the problem

Any idea what could be the problem or where to investigate?

Summary :

Not logged in the backend

When reloading page with ctrl+R, reload the same page: KO

When reloading page with ctrl+MAJ+R, reload the same page: KO

logged in backend

When reloading page with ctrl+R, reload the same page: KO

When reloading page with ctrl+MAJ+R, load the target page: OK

Answer (score 0):

Please Update TYPO3 version 6.1 does not get any security updates. This means you running an security risk. And might be liable. And my guess not many active community members are able to help you as your versions are ancient

Comment: Unfortunatly this site cannot be updated :(